# javascript get percentage of likes and dislikes

Tags: javascript, react-native, operators, percentage

I have likes and dislikes and I try to find the percentage of both.
The problem is sometimes there is no likes and dislikes so I can't make the calcul.
The second problem is, the && operator doesn't work..

```js
if (likes == 0 && dislike == 0) {
        setLikePercentage(50);
        setDislikePercentage(50);
    } else if (likes == 0) {
        setLikePercentage(0);
        setDislikePercentage(100);
    } else if (dislikes == 0) {
        setLikePercentage(100);
        setDislikePercentage(0);
    } else {
        setLikePercentage((likes / (dislikes + likes)) * 100);
        setDislikePercentage((dislikes / (dislikes + likes)) * 100);
    }
```

any solutions to fix it?

Comment: "Doesn't work" in what way? What happens when you run this code? Have you confirmed that the values are what you expect (`console.log(likes, dislikes)`)?

Comment: @GuyIncognito if I log it, console return `0 0`, so this is good values, and this automatically go to the `else if (likes == 0)`

Comment: Maybe it's because you have `&& dislike == 0` instead of `dislikes` with the s at the end?

Comment: There is not enough code here to know what you're actually doing. - Your code states setLikePercentage and setDislikePercentage as functions. Where are these functions? Where are the like/dislike vars?

Answer (score 1):

You could shrink the code to a check of same values, which includes both zero values and another for calculating the percent values.

```
if (likes === dislikes) {
    setLikePercentage(50);
    setDislikePercentage(50);
} else {
    setLikePercentage((likes / (dislikes + likes)) * 100);
    setDislikePercentage((dislikes / (dislikes + likes)) * 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify things by making the general assumption that if both `likes` and `dislikes` are the same value, they are 50%. In all other scenarios, you just want to run the calculation.

This way, you can get rid of your first 3 `if/else if` statements. I am also assuming that `likes` and `dislikes` will never be less than 0.

```js
/**
* Main Calcation
*/
const doCalculation = (likes, dislikes) => {
  likes = likes && likes > 0 ? likes : 0;
  dislikes = dislikes && dislikes > 0 ? dislikes : 0;
  if (likes === dislikes) { return { likes: 50, dislikes: 50 }; }
  const total = likes + dislikes;
  return {
    likes: (likes / total) * 100,
    dislikes: (dislikes / total) * 100
  };
};

/**
* For event handling/presentation purposes
*/
const calculateLikes = () => {
  const likes = document.getElementById('likes').value
  const dislikes = document.getElementById('dislikes').value
  const result = doCalculation(+likes, +dislikes);
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = `
    <div>Likes: ${result.likes}%</div>
    Dislikes: ${result.dislikes}%
  `;
};

// Events
document.getElementById('likes').addEventListener( 'keyup', calculateLikes );
document.getElementById('dislikes').addEventListener( 'keyup', calculateLikes );
```

```html
<input placeholder="likes" id="likes" />
<input placeholder="dislikes" id="dislikes" />

<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

before your if condition add these two lines;

```
//check null status
likes = likes || 0;
dislikes = dislikes || 0;

if (likes == 0 && dislike == 0) {
...
```

`||` is the boolean OR operator. As in javascript, `undefined, null, 0, false` are considered as falsy values.